# Unable to return the client secret in a PowerShell (filepath) referencing from variable group linked in CI pipeline

Tags: powershell, shell, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have defined secret "ClientSecret" in a variable group as  and linked it to the CI pipeline.
The client secret is marked as secret and hidden in the library.
but the secret is not returning when referring from powershell script file.

Below is the code:

```
**PS Script**
param (
$Secret = $Env:ClientSecret
)

$UpdateValues = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://storage123.table.core.windows.net/tabletest(PartitionKey='test'" + ",RowKey='" + $Id+ "')" + '"$Secret"')) -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing

write-output ("https://storage123.table.core.windows.net/tabletest(PartitionKey='test'" + ",RowKey='" + $Id+ "')" + '"$Secret"')
```

```
**write output returning below:** 

https://storage123.table.core.windows.net/tabletest(PartitionKey='test'
+
,RowKey='
+
123+
')
+
```

```
Since the secret marked as hidden in variable group, it should return as asterisks like below:

https://storage123.table.core.windows.net/tabletest(PartitionKey='test'
+
,RowKey='
+
123+
')
+
***
```

Comment: Environmental variables can only contain string classes, anything else will converted to a string unsing the dedault ``ToString()` method of the concerned class. I guess that the initial "ClientSecret" is not a string class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the secret variable in Azure Pipeline, you need to explicitly map secret variables in Agent Job.

You can add environment variable in PowerShell task to map secret variables. Then you can get the `***` value.

Here is an example:

**PowerShell Script:**

```
param (
$Secret = $Env:ClientSecret
)

echo "$Secret"
```

**Pipeline PowerShell task**:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./test.ps1
  env:
    ClientSecret: $(ClientSecret)
```

**Result:**

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Secret Variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)